# Setting a variable to a defined lazy var within a UIView closure cause reference problems

Tags: swift, uiview, lazy-initialization

Recently, I was working on a project of mine and I wanted to have multiple labels with the same font, text color, and properties, except their text.

This is the code I wrote:

```
lazy var profileLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = .displayNameLabel
    label.textColor = .profileLabel
    label.numberOfLines = .numberOfLines
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return label
}()

lazy var displayName: UILabel = {
    let label = profileLabel
    label.text = "Kevin"

    return label
}()

lazy var countryLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = profileLabel
    label.text = "US"

    return label
}()
```

As you can see, to remedy my issue, I created a single label that had all the properties I wanted for all my other labels. For my other labels, I thought I was creating a new label by typing `let label = profileLabel`. But as it turns out, I wasn't. After consecutive calls of setting the text and adding the labels to my view, only 1 label was actually displayed, and it was the last label added; so in this case, it would be the `countryLabel`.

It seems to me that in all my calls to let `label = profileLabel`, I'm just creating a reference to the same `profileLabel`. And if this is the case, would changing `lazy var profileLabel` to `var profileLabel` fix this issue and create a new label with the needed properties every time `profileLabel` is called?

Comment: Instead of initialising your property(which creates a single reference point, i.e. an instance), just cut the `lazy` part and don't add the `()` at the end of declaration. It will yield the exact behaviour that you're looking for. Refer Subramanian's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were intended to use computed property of swift. But didn’t get it right. Your profile label should have been defined as follows.

```
var profileLabel: UILabel {
   get {
      let label = UILabel()
      label.font = .displayNameLabel
      label.textColor = .profileLabel
      label.numberOfLines = .numberOfLines
      label.textAlignment = .center
      label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      return label
   }
}
```